# Circumventing Python errors in a script

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I have a large file containing thousands of links. I've written a script calling each link line-by-line and performing various analyses on the respective webpage. However, sometimes it is the case that the link is faulty (article removed from website, etc), and my whole script just stops at that point.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Here's my (pseudo)code:

```
for row in file:
    url = row[4]
    req=urllib2.Request(url)
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
    perform analyses
    append analyses results to lists
output data
```

I have tried

```
except:
    pass
```

But it royally messes up the script for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
for row in file:
    url = row[4]
    try:
        req=urllib2.Request(url)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
        perform analyses
        append analyses results to lists
    except URLError, e:
        pass
output data
```

Comment: Do you mean to put the try/except block inside the for loop? Otherwise it will stop at that line, exactly the problem the OP wants to avoid

Comment: Oh god its getting late. I'm not thinking 100% Thank you for the corection

Answer (score 0):

Try block is the way to go:

```
for row in file:
url = row[4]
    try:
        req=urllib2.Request(url)
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
    except URLError, e:
        continue
    perform analyses
    append analyses results to lists
output data
```

Continue will allow you to skip any unnecessary computation after the url check and restart at the next iteration of the loop